# How to construct a sampling distribution for a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I'm having some trouble with a homework assignment, it goes as follows:

> **27.** Suppose that certain electronic components have lifetimes that are exponentially distributed: $f(t \mid \tau) = \frac{1}{\tau}\exp(−t/\tau)$, $t \geq 0$. Five new components are put on
> test, the first one fails at $100$ days, and no further observations are recorded.
>
> **a.** What is the likelihood function of $\tau$?
>
> **b.** What is the MLE of $\tau$?
>
> **c.** What is the sampling distribution of the MLE?
>
> **d.** What is the standard error of the MLE?

The idea in this question is that if one electric component fails, all of them fail. So I was able to do **a** and **b**, the likelihood function is:

$$ l(\tau \mid t_1, \ldots ,t_5) = \frac{1}{\tau}e^{\frac{T}{\tau}} $$

Where $T$ is the time that the first electric component fails.
Using the log likelihood, deriving it and setting it equal to $0$ gives us: $\hat{\tau} = 5T$.

However I'm stuck at **c** because I don't know how to construct a sampling distribution of the MLE. I've tried looking through my book but I couldn't find a clear example. The answers say it should be $\hat{\tau} \sim e^{\frac{1}{\tau}}$.

Comment: What does $\hat{\tau} \sim \frac{1}{\tau}$ mean?  A uniform distribution on $[0,\tau]$ with constant density $\frac{1}{\tau}$? Or something else?

Comment: If you know $\hat \tau = 5 T$ where $T$ is the time of the first failure, I would have thought you want to find the distribution of $T$ and then rescale it to get the sampling distribution of $\hat \tau$

Comment: Hey @Henry, thanks for your response. I made a mistake, the answer should be $e^{\frac{1}{\tau}}$ and I was confused what that answer meant aswell. I'm gonna try to find the distribution of T thank you

Comment: $\hat \tau \sim e^{\frac{1}{\tau}}$ probably means that $\hat \tau$ has an exponential distribution with rate $\frac 1\tau$ i.e. mean $\tau$.  This looks plausible (it is also the distribution of the lifetime of each component)